# Black image after performing perspective transformation on Android + OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have 4 points representing  4 corners of a distorted rectangle. I tried to calculate the perspective transformation and apply to my image; but all I get is a black image. Can anyone help please ? I tried to different options and none of them works. Here are my snippets:

1. //////////////////////////////////////

   ```
   Mat cropped_image;
   cropped_image = original.clone();


        Mat pointsDES = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32F);
        Mat pointsSRC = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32F);
        pointsDES.put(0,300,0,0,800,0,800,300,0,300);
   ```

   pointsSRC.put((int)coin.x,(int)coin.y,(int)coin1.x,(int)coin1.y,(int)coin2.x,(int)coin2.y,(int)coin3.x,(int)coin3.y,(int)coin.x,(int)coin.y);

   Mat perspectiveTransform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(pointsSRC,pointsDES); Imgproc.warpPerspective(original,cropped_image,perspectiveTransform,cropped_image.size());
2. /////////////////////////////

   List dst_pnt = new ArrayList();
           Point p4 = new Point(0.0, 500.0);
           dst_pnt.add(p4);
           Point p5 = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
           dst_pnt.add(p5);
           Point p6 = new Point(800.0, 0.0);
           dst_pnt.add(p6);
           Point p7 = new Point(800.0, 500.0);
           dst_pnt.add(p7);

   ```
       List<Point> src_pnt = new ArrayList<Point>();
       src_pnt.add(coin);
       src_pnt.add(coin1);
       src_pnt.add(coin2);
       src_pnt.add(coin3);

       Mat startM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(src_pnt);
       Mat endM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(dst_pnt);

       Mat perspectiveTransform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(startM, endM);
       Size size = new Size(5000, 8000);
       Scalar scalar = new Scalar(50.0);
       Mat outputMat = new Mat();
       Imgproc.warpPerspective(original, outputMat, perspectiveTransform, size);
   ```

Comment: use function perspectiveTransform on points  (0,0) (0,height) (width,0) and (width,height) and test whether their position falls into your output image at all. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void perspectiveTransform(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray m)

Comment: I just tried this: Mat perspectiveTransform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(pointsDES,pointsDES); and I got a black image anyway ...

Comment: use the function perspectiveTransform and print the result please.

Comment: Just printed the matrix:  [0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 1]

Comment: perspectiveTransform computes points. But if that is your computed homography then it's no wonder that you get a nonsense result

Comment: I should get an identity matrix in this case, but I'm not and I have no clue why ...

Comment: instead of matrices can you try to use array of 2d points as input?

Comment: You mean this type of arrays: List<Point> src_pnt = new ArrayList<Point>();    ?

Comment: I don't know how it is used in java. In C++ you would use `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` which is some kind of dynamic array. Probably there's some similar type supported by openCV for java, too.

Comment: Okay I'll try that. I just printed both matrices containing my points, and they're just zeros ... I'll try with the 2D array

Comment: or maybe try `List<Point2f> src_pnt = new ArrayList<Point2f>();` since you try to convert point2f to mat. But if possible, array/list of points is often more easy to use

Comment: Okay so I tried with the list. List<Point2f> is not possible but we can convert it like this: Mat startM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(src_pnt); I tried again and my problem was when I declared the output image. I only did: Mat outputMat = new Mat() instead of : Mat outputMat = new Mat(800, 500, CvType.CV_8UC1); and now it works like a charm ! Thanks very much for the support !